Declaring a variable of a typed class
I have an issue about typed classes in C# that I can't correct :
I have a generic class which declaration look like that :
    public abstract class AbstractControler<T> where T : IModelWithId

Where IModelWithId is an interface.
I have a second class that extends the first one which declaration look like that :
    internal class SquadronsControler : AbstractControler<Squadron>

Where, you guessed Squadron is a class implementing the interface IModelWithId.
My issue is that, in a third class, I want to store different children of AbstractControler in a variable and I can't find a way to declare and assign it that don't lead to a compilation error.
Property declaration I tried :
internal AbstractControler<IModelWithId> Controler { get; set; }

And then, when I try to assign this property (Note : SquadronControler is a Singleton)...
Controler = SquadronsControler.getInstance();

... I have a error CS0029 implicit cast not allowed.
I tried an explicit cast with no success (obtained a CS0030) instead...
I can't use the solution proposed in this question : Declare variable of a generic class as I need the generic type in both in an out ways.
Can someone point me to the correct direction to do what I want ?
EDIT : I guess there could be something done as my AbstractControler is typed with an implementor of IModelWithId and my SquadronControler is typed with a Squadron that implements IModelWithId. So conceptually, there could be a solution to cast my SquadronControler<Squadron> to a SquadronControler<IModelWithId> that should be compatible.

"Can someone point me to the correct direction to do what I want ?" - I am actually not really sure what you want, exactly. But: Given classes A and B : A , then GenericClass<B> is still not a GenericClass<A>. They would be two completely unrelated types.

Best thing to do is probably to make another base class or an interface, which is not generic, so you have public abstract class AbstractController<T> : AbstractControllerBase where T : IModelWithId. Then you can have internal AbstractControllerBase Controler { get; set; }

You probably want to take a look at variance. If you can change your abstract class to an interface and make it covariant it should solve your problem

"as I need the generic type in both in an out ways" Why do you have to return AbstractControler<IModelWithId> instead of a non-generic AbstractControler?

The reason this isn't allowed is a zoo of animals. Imagine a List<Animal>. If you could do what you want here, it would be possible to do this: var giraffes = List<Giraffe>(); ((List<Animal>)giraffes).Add(new Lion()). There might be valid scenarios for that, which is why we have co-variance. However we have no clue about your domain and if this is indeed such a scenario.
